Google Authentication with Django and Flutter
I created a mobile app called Dermalens, which tests whether a skin lesion is benign or not. The app is developed using Flutter for the frontend and Django for the backend. When a user signs in from the Flutter app, they are requesting a JWT token. During sign-up, a new object is created from the Account model, which is a customized built-in user model in Django. Whenever a user uploads an image for testing, an object from the SkinImage model is created, which has a many-to-one relationship with the Account model. My problem is that I want to add Google authentication to the mobile app. How can I achieve that?
